# Cron expression running every 30 mins

Tags: spring, cronexpression

I have one spring job to run every 30 minutes:-
Suppose current time is 1:55 pm, now it should run at 2:25 pm, 2:55pm, 3:25 pm & so on.

This cron expression is not working for me:-
"0 0/30 * * * ?"

Comment: may be the problem is not in your cron expression. please post additional info about project config.

Answer (score 1):

This timespec would run your job on the 25th and 55th minute of every hour, every day:

25,55 * * * *

Comment: like "0 0,10 * * * ?"   So it will fire on minutes 0 and 10 of each hour.

Comment: That would be 0,10 * * * *   The first field specifies the minutes of the hour. The example you provide in your comment would run the cron job at 00:00 and 10:00 every day.

Answer (score 1):

@Scheduled(cron="0 0/30 * * * ?") will trigger first when it reaches any *:30 or *:00. So in your case it will trigger at 2:00pm, 2:30pm, 3:00pm and so on.

If you want your job to run every 30minutes. You can use fixedRate or fixedDelay.

@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1800000) will first trigger your job at 1:55pm. If you want to skip first iteration you can add initialDelay=1800000.

Answer (score 0):

25,55 * * * * your command >/dev/null 2>&1

You can easly generate a crontab via this website, even with no experience.

The problem is that you have to know the starting time of your cron job.

http://crontab-generator.org/